# C typedef enum compilation

Tags: c, performance

Does using `typedef enum { VALUE_1 = 0x00, ... } typeName;` have any more overhead in C (specifically, compiling using AVR-GCC for an AVR MCU) than doing `typedef unsigned char typeName;` and then just defining each value with `#define VALUE_1 0x00`?

My specific application is status codes that can be returned and checked by functions. It seems neater to me to use the `typedef enum` style, but I wanted to be sure that it wasn't going to add any significant overhead to the compiled application.

I would assume no, but I wasn't really sure. I tried to look for similar questions but most of them pertained to C++ and got more specific answers to C++.

Comment: No, enum's are compile-time constants in C also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `enum` declaration creates an *enumerated type*. Such a type is compatible with (and therefore has the same size and representation as) some predefined integer type, but the compiler chooses which one.

But the enumeration constants are always of type `int`. (This differs from C++, where the constants are of the enumerated type.)

So `typedef unsigned char ...` vs. `typedef enum ...` will likely change the size and representation of the *type*, which can matter if you define objects of the type or functions that return the type, but the constants `VALUE_1` et al will be of type `int` either way.

It's probably best to use the `enum` type; that way the compiler can decide what representation is best.  Your alternative of specifying `unsigned char` will minimize storage, but depending on the platform it might actually slow down access to objects relative to, say, using something compatible with `int`.

Incidentally, the typedef isn't strictly necessary. If you prefer, you can use a *tag*:

```
enum typeName { Value_1 = 0x00, ... };
```

But then you have to refer to the type as `enum typeName` rather than just `typeName`. The advantage of `typedef` is that it lets you give the type a name that's just a single identifier.